# Загрузка pdf файла с сервера node

Tags: pdf, node.js

У меня есть сайт, серверная часть которого написана на `node.js`. Как мне сделать так, что бы клиенты могли загружать `pdf` файлы с сайта?

Answer (score 4):

### Любое из:

- Отдавайте вебсервером **перед** NodeJS просто как статические файлы.

  - Скажем, [nginx и директива `try_files`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) попытается по адресу отдать статический файл в указанном месте, а если не удастся, передаст запрос куда-то ещё, в зависимости от настроек.
  - Если вы используете другой вебсервер, не nginx, смотрите его документацию. В целом, отдавать статические файлы предпочтительно **минуя** NodeJS, поскольку это лишний расход ресурсов, когда есть вебсерверы, расходующие ресурсы для решения такой простой задачи куда эффективнее.
- Отдавайте обычным HTTP-ответом (взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046039/nodejs-send-file-in-response), правда, это про mp3, для PDF придётся заменить `Content-Type`):

  ```
  http.createServer(function(request, response) {
      var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'myfile.mp3');
      var stat = fileSystem.statSync(filePath);

      response.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
          'Content-Length': stat.size
      });

      var readStream = fileSystem.createReadStream(filePath);
      readStream.pipe(response);
  })
  .listen(2000);
  ```
- Комбинация: отдать файл по указанию приложения через обратный прокси. Например, [nginx и `X-Accel-Redirect`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/): когда возвращающийся через прокси ответ содержит этот заголовок, nginx вместо передачи ответа дальше отдаст его клиенту файл по указанному пути.

  - В отличие от отдачи файлов просто nginx'ом, запрос всё же дойдёт до приложения, и приложение сможет решить, отдавать ли файл вообще (можно вкрутить авторизацию), и если да, то какой (по одному пути можно отдавать разным людям разные файлы).
  - Но в отличие от полной обработки запроса приложением, получив заголовки, обратный прокси отсоединится от приложения и будет сам отправлять то, что ему сказали. Приложение тем временем, в зависимости от архитектуры, может заняться другим запросом от пользователя.
  - Есть и [модуль для Apache](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/), оперирует заголовком `X-SENDFILE`.